# TS1109, WebStorm incorrectly reacting on optional chaining

Tags: typescript, webstorm, optional-chaining

[image: Ts1109 error]

WebStorm thinks it is a ternary operator and expects expressions and colon next. Maybe it thinks it is a TS code, while this is JS code in .js file, I'm not sure.

How can I switch this inspection off?

Comment: That looks like a ts error. what extension does your file have? Optional chaining is not supported in TS, and in JS you probably need some babel plugin to get it to work it is not in the standard yet it is at stage 1 (https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) The only place I know of that supports this out of the box are angular templates..

Comment: It is js file with .js extension. I have plugin installed, project compiles and works, it is only webstorm lint error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TypeScript compiler service reports the error here because optional chaining is not supported in TypeScript < [3.7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7-beta/). Service is used for JavaScript linting if the service is enabled in *Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript* and `"allowJs"` is set to `true` in `tsconfig.json`.

If you only want the service to compile/lint TypeScript, make sure that `"allowJs"` is either not set or set to `false` in  `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue, then **updating webstorm** to this verion worked. So simple solution is updating the webstorm version. Make sure you are using typescript **version 3.7 or above** since optional chaining is supported in later versions only.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As of 2019-10-01, optional chaining is available in TypeScript 3.7 beta.

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7-beta/

I don't know if the current version of WebStorm can be configured to use the beta, but the early release version (2019.3 EAP #5) supports TypeScript 3.7.

- https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2019/10/webstorm-2019-3-eap-5/